# Is there a reasonable way to add to dictionary values without importing libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I was working on a practice problem where the user has an inventory saved as a dictionary, say for example:

```
inventory = {
    'rope': 1,
    'gold coin': 42,
    }
```

Then, I needed to modify it by adding "loot" to the inventory later on.

So for example:

```
loot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
```

I ended up doing this fairly easily by using `Counter` within `collections` like so:

```
def add_to_inventory(original_inventory, added_items):
    new_inventory = Counter(original_inventory) + Counter(added_items)
    return(new_inventory)

inventory = add_to_inventory(inventory, loot)
```

With the result being:

```
45: gold coin
1: rope
1: ruby
1: dagger
```

Which is all well and fine, but I was wondering.. **Is there a reasonable way to solve this without having to import a library?**

Comment: What is the problem with importing a library? You should use `collections.defaultdict` BTW.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the tip! Nothing is wrong with using the library, I like to just know of alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a `dict`'s `get` method:

```
inventory = {'rope': 1, 'gold coin': 42,}
loot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

for k in loot:
    inventory[k] = inventory.get(k, 0) + 1

print inventory
```

Output:

```
{'rope': 1, 'gold coin': 45, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1}
```

Comment: I did not even think to this, best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply loop through the inventory and increment key if it exists, else initiate the value to 1, using the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach:

```
for l in loot:
    try:
        inventory[l] += 1
    except KeyError:
        inventory[l] = 1
```

As you talk about alternatives, there is also the [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object from `collections` module which is **very** useful:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inventory = defaultdict(int)
for l in loot:
    inventory[l] += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

same answer that Delgan given, but we can use setdefault to initialize

```
def add_to_inventory(inventory, loot):
    for l in loot:
        inventory[l] = inventory.setdefault(l, 0) + 1
```